# Angular2 *ngFor not displaying array data

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm using Angular 5 and doing a crash course. I've actually gotten further than just using an ngFor directive, but I'm doing part of a practice assignment and one of the first things I'm trying to do won't loop to display data. I have other projecdts where it's working but this one doesn't and I'm baffled. Know it's something silly.

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  subscriptions: ['Basic', 'Advanced', 'Pro'];
}
```

HTML Template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12>
      <p *ngFor="let subscription of subscriptions">{{subscription}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple, yeah? I was actually putting it into an option element for a select input, but that didn't work and so I figured I'd try something even simpler and it still won't work. THe resultant html has this  where the content would go, but I'm not versed enough to know what that really means.

thanks

Comment: `subscriptions: ['Basic', 'Advanced', 'Pro'];` is setting the type. You need to assign the value with `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the array value

```
 subscriptions =  ['Basic', 'Advanced', 'Pro'];
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-wdr8sj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Adding to this if I was you I wouldn't use types (or myvariable: myType) as of yet until you get the hang of TypeScript or Angular. It will just complicate your life. Is not needed either way in most occasions. When you need it you will know ;)

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you. I knew it was something silly. I've been training for weeks non-stop and I'm tired. I appreciate it. Will accept as answer when I can (have to wait 10 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You can display each array data in list Using `*ngFor` in Angular.

This array assign is wrong in your code.

```
export class AppComponent {
  subscriptions: ['Basic', 'Advanced', 'Pro'];
}
```

Array assign should be :

```
export class AppComponent {
  subscriptions =  ['Basic', 'Advanced', 'Pro'];
}
```

[more details](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)